# I wanna display 6 squares in one container (height of the container is 1/3 of the screen) like the given image How to do?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I want to display 6 squares in  fixed size of a container (height of the container is 1/3 of the screen) like the given image I got it but its not responsive when I run multiple emulator the square changed to rectangle I want exact 6 squares in a fixed size of container how to do and how to make responsive?

I want to display like the given image(responsive)

Comment: can you include your code-snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following code:
you're code will overflow because you may be using padding

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Container_(),
                  Container_(),
                  Container_(),
                ],
              ),
              Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, children: [
                Container_(),
                Container_(),
                Container_(),
              ])
            ]),
      )),
    );
  }
}

class Container_ extends StatelessWidget {
  const Container_({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3 - 18,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3 - 18,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12), color: Colors.indigo),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMy0x.png

Comment: cheers bruh..got it can u explain what it mean by MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3 - 18??

Comment: `mediaQuery.of(context).size.width` is the width of screen. `/3` divided by 3 to get third part of screen and removed 18 pixels because was using 3px padding '3 * 6 = 18'